# Statistically collecting rounding error in a program (C)

Tags: c, bash, histogram

I wrote a program that compute 1000000! using FFT.

(please allow me to be short and omit some theoretical resoning :) )

What i want to do is measure ALL the rounding error between a double value and is `round()`-ed value (using `math.h` function) to check how this error is behaving (and if it is above 1/2).

I'm doing so by printing the difference between `a` and `round(a)` each time i do rounding, and write the result into a file, let's call it `diffs.txt`, which is `~532Mb`, using

`fprintf(my_file,"%e\n",a-round(a));`

I now need to count the occurrence of every single value that appear in that file.

I'm doing so by what it seems to me an intricate way, using `grep`, `sort` and a bash `for` as follow:

```
./compute-rounding-err #It creates diffs.txt
sort -u diffs.txt -o diff-sorted-unique
for i in `cat diff-sorted-unique`
do
 grep -e "$i" | wc -l >> diff-counted
done
```

The result is two file. If i pair that files i obtain

```
diff-sorted-unique:     diff_counted:
-9.013892e-20           1           
...                     ...
0.000000e0              200
...                     ...
9.930234e               1
```

I can take these values and make an histogram out of them.

My fear is that doing so on a laptop with a `~532Mb` file will take a long time.

Anyone knows how to speed things up?

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Do you actually need a ~532 Mb (523*10^6 bits? 532 MiB?) file, or do you only need a histogram (for some unknown/obscure reason), or do you only need to know the worst case error? What are you doing about the error caused by using `double` (where the significand  is far too small to cope with 10000! without cumulative precision loss)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that you are writing each 8-byte double with 11-12 characters, then the overall memory you need should be around ~450MB, which means the number of items you have should be around 50,000,000.

Sorting 50 million values shouldn't take long. What will take long is your `for` loop where you scan the whole file for every item.

A more efficient way would be to sort the file, but keep the duplicate values. Then, all you need is one pass over the file, grouping similar values (or equal values, based on the precision of your histogram) and replace them with a value-count pair.

For example, if you have the following file:

```
1
0.6
-2
0
-1
-0.6
0
0
3
```

After sort you will get:

```
-2
-1
-0.6
0
0
0
0.6
1
3
```

And if you follow this algorithm:

```
current_bucket = first value in file, floored to histogram_precision
bucket_count = 0
for all values v
    ; write current bucket + additional empty buckets
    while v > current_bucket + histogram_precision
        output   current_bucket   bucket_count
        current_bucket += histogram precision
        bucket_count = 0
    ; add v to current_bucket
    bucket_count += 1
```

given `histogram_precision` as 1 for example, you will get:

```
-2       1
-1       2
0        4
1        1
2        0
3        1
```

where each line `num count` shows the number of values (`count`) in the range `[num, num+histogram_precision)`.

You may want to use buckets like `[0.5, 1.5)` for example instead of `[1 2)`, in which case you should just tweak the first line where the initial bucket is computed, or alternatively change the condition of `while` loop to `v > current_bucket + histogram_precision / 2`.

Comment: You answer is theoretically good, but I was looking for a pratical implementation of it using bash or whatever you like :) Sorry for not being explicit about that.

Comment: Contrary to what you have heard, Stackoverflow isn't a source for free programming. @shahbaz has given you an excellent pseudo-code description of what you need to do. You're welcome to post here follow up questions with sample input, required sample output, code you have created, any error messages and current output from that code with questions about how to resolve your problem.

Comment: @AlessandroL., I'm not an `awk` expert, but I believe that algorithm should be as short as what I wrote there if implemented with `awk`. Even in C it wouldn't be more than 15 lines.

Comment: I cannot understand how you would deal with this.                                                                Theoretical expected error is in (-0.5,0.5) but sampled error actually assumes random values that are significantly smaller than the expected range. For example I have these values, represented as a couple value,# of occurencies: (-8.731149e-11 , 342), ... , (-2.328306e-10,4369) , (0.000,45981), ... (6.585445e-10,1721).

Comment: Nevertheless these values are really few differents value: ONLY 19!!! So what I'm missing here is How will you set you bin precision? I mean, I'm expecting to have a Gaussian centered in 0 that assumes values between +-0.5 but what I'm getting are very dense values in a very little fraction of my expected range. Hope I'm not abusing stackoverflow.

Comment: Well you have to experiment with the values. The first value, you can put to a safe minimum. The precision, well, if it is too small, you will put one number in each bucket and many buckets would be empty. It won't look good. On the other hand, if you make it too big, then you will see all your data in a few buckets, which again doesn't look good.

Comment: So what I'm trying to say is that "histogram_precision" depends on the nature of your data. Try playing with it until you get a value that is most helpful.

Comment: Also, if you are getting values mostly in only a fraction of your expected range, then it probably means that most of the times your errors are very small, which is a good thing. It is still a Gaussian centered at 0, but with a small variance. In that case, decreasing the precision a bit _may_ give a visually better graph.

Comment: What I'm getting doesn't looks like as a Gaussian with small variance, since extreme values (which are still really smaller than the expected) have more occurences than the internal values. And i cannot understand if it's me that i'm missing something or if it is still a good thing.

Comment: @AlessandroL., if you look at the sorted data (without removing uniques), do you see the same phenomenon? If so, then the problem is in your data gathering, or maybe your errors don't follow Gaussian!

Comment: I don't understand. What do you mean?

Comment: I'm saying, look at the sorted file, and count manually a couple of data. See if they are compatible with the graph that you made.

Comment: I have 42millions of sample. How can I do that? :)

Comment: Well ...  Have you tried plotting the histogram with Matlab or something? Load the file in matlab and there should be a function for it. Just to compare the results.

Comment: Ok, I got it. It looks like there's an error in the script I reported in the question. There are many samples that doesn't appear in the sorted file. I'm a complete dumb.

Comment: @AlessandroL., it's not the first time a piece of code has a bug, don't feel so bad ;)